# Htaccess rewrite rules?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, clean-urls, friendly-url

so my url is currently:

> http://www.mywebsite.com/search.php?keyword=stack+overflow

I'm wanting to have it accessible as:

> http://www.mywebsite.com/?s=stack+overflow

Now I've also implemented rewrites for .php files as below

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

I'm a little confused now because the `search.php` is being rewritten to just `search` but is still accessable with `search.php`, so when I create my rewrite rule do I rewrite `search.php` or just `search`?.. either way I've tried and failed to accomplish it lol.

What should I add to have my desired url? Help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible to change parameter name with mod_rewrite. The easiest way to achieve what you want is to add these lines to .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s=
RewriteRule .? search.php [L]
```

and modify search.php to react to `s` get parameter the same as it reacts to `keyword`.

An alternative is to keep .htaccess intact and add these at the top of index.php:

```
if (!empty($_GET['s'])) {
    $_GET['keyword'] = $_GET['s'];
    require __DIR__ . '/search.php';
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Ahhh okay, well I did as you suggested with the change of parameter easy enough. Thank you :)

Comment: it's possible to change parameter name with mod_rewrite.

Comment: How? Can you give an example or link to one?